# Can a Titanium iOS module access files in the Titanium app?

Tags: objective-c, module, titanium, clipboard, gif

I have run into [a few dead ends](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/136205/copy-animated-gif-to-clipboard-pass-image-path-or-binary-data-to-module) trying to get an animated gif onto the clipboard in iOS using Titanium, so that I can then have the user paste it into an MMS.

I am considering trying my hand at creating a simple Titanium Module to get the image onto the clipboard with Objective C. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982492/want-to-paste-gif-into-mail-window-using-uipasteboard) has the code to do it.

My question is, can the Titanium Module access the file I have in my Titanium app's Resources folder? If so, I can just pass a path into the module.

If not, then I may need to pass the binary image data into the module (which probably won't work, since using a blob to put the image on the clipboard does not work)

Another approach might be to put all the images inside the module itself.

Comment: The answer is yes. NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" 
                                                         ofType:@"txt"
                                                    inDirectory:@"subfoldername"];

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same thing but with no luck. I have images in my /Resources folder and would like to access them from within iOS module but can't do that. Do you pass TiFile or string from JS code?